# deploy goal failing to upload artifacts in artifactory after artifactory upgrade

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-plugin

I recently migrated the Artifactory from 3.9.0 to 6.1.0 and when I initiate a Maven build on server it fails while deploying the artifacts in the rtifactory and gives the below error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
(default-deploy) on project reference-data: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not
 transfer artifact be.fgov.minfin.masp.referencedata:reference-data:war:0.0.1-20181207.150840-2 from/to IN (http://inmbzp7060.in.dst.ibm.com:8081
/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project
 reference-data: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact 
be.fgov.minfin.masp.referencedata:reference-data:war:0.0.1-20181207.150840-2 from/to
 IN (http://inmbzp7060.in.dst.ibm.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/): 
Connection reset
```

Comment: Network issue:`Connection reset -..`

Comment: @khmarbaise, it is not related to network issue. It downloads certain information of the artifact but then stops abruptly and connection error comes.

Comment: So artifactory is configured wrong!?...

Comment: I had done the exact same configuration as for the earlier one

Comment: Did you check artifactory logs? check artifactory.log and request.log

Comment: In request.log, following is shown:

20181218181003|31|REQUEST|9.121.57.192|non_authenticated_user|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/be/fgov/minfin/masp/pdie/PDIE/3.18.0-SNAPSHOT/PDIE-3.18.0-20181218.123715-54.pom|HTTP/1.1|401|19319